# Name for classes of algebras closed under products and quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, universal-algebra

A class of algebras closed under products, quotients and subalgebras is a [variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)). Is there a name for a class of algebras closed under products and quotients? Could you refer me to any theorems about such classes of algebras?

Comment: One reference for the relation among the operators $H$, $S$ and $P$ is the paper by  Pigozzi in the following link http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02945045.

Comment: Can you tell us a natural example for such a class?